# cannot compile the CUDA code when splitted into several files

Tags: c, cuda, nvcc

I'm writing this simple cuda code and I'm unable to compile it. The code contains part of code written in C. This is the structure of the program:

read_data.c file contains a function called read_data
add.cu file contains a function called add (this is the part that should run in the GPGPU)
optimize.h file contains the necessary headers.
master.c file contains the main function.

The optimize.h file looks like follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

__global__ void add(int, float*, float*);
void read_data(char*, float**, float**, int**);
```

master.c file looks like follows:

```
#include "optimize.h"

int main(){
    char* path = "./data/0";
    float* base_load;
    float* comfortable_temperatures;
    int* comfort_index;

    read_data(path, &base_load, &comfortable_temperatures, &comfort_index);
    int N = 1<<20;
    float *x, *y;
    int i;

    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));
  
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       x[i] = 1.0f;
       y[i] = 2.0f;
    }
    add<<<1, 256>>>(N, x, y);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // still need to read the result back.

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);
   }
```

I compiled this using the following line:

```
nvcc -o master master.c read_data.c add.cu
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
In file included from master.c:1:0:
optimize.h:9:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
 __global__ void add(int, float*, float*);
            ^
master.c: In function ‘main’:
master.c:51:26: error: ‘add’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                          add<<<1, 256>>>(N, x, y);
                          ^
master.c:51:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
master.c:51:31: error: expected expression before ‘<’ token
                          add<<<1, 256>>>(N, x, y);
```

I think the whatever the error is, it should be a very small one. But I cannot find it.

Comment: Files that end in `.c` or `.cpp` are processed mostly by your host compiler.  Your host compiler doesn't understand CUDA syntax.  Since you intend to call a kernel from your `master.c` file, possibly the simplest option is to rename that file to `master.cu`  This is the usual recommendation for code containing CUDA syntax: it should be in a `.cu` file.  This will affect the linking process to your `read_data.c` file, so the simplest option there may be to rename that as `read_data.cpp` or `read_data.cu`.  You can also try just passing the `-x cu` file as a compile switch, without file changes.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you! That worked! If you want to add this as an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvcc` by default treats filenames ending in `.c` or `.cpp` as having no CUDA-specific syntax, and sends those to the host compiler.  The host compiler cannot handle CUDA-specific syntax, which is why you are getting the errors.

The usual recommendations are to place your CUDA code in files ending with `.cu`.  You can alternatively pass `-x cu` as a compile switch to do this.

Note that `nvcc` uses c++ style linkage, so you will need to arrange for correct c-style linkage if you are trying to link code in a `.cu` file with code in a `.c` file.  If you have no C-specific usage, again, a simple solution may be to rename your `.c` file to `.cpp` or `.cu`.

There are many questions here on the `cuda` tag explaining how to do C++/C linkage, otherwise.